# every closed ball is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be in metric $\left(X , \rho\right)$ every closed ball is compact.
Prove that in that case for any point $x \in X$ and for any closed subset $A = [A] \subseteq X$ there exists a point $a \in A$, that $\rho(x,a) = \inf_{a' \in A}\rho\left(x,a'\right) $

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $r > 0$ large enough that $B(x,r) \cap A \ne \varnothing$, where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. Then $\overline{B(x,r)} \cap A$ is a closed subset of a compact set, and therefore is compact.

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset A \cap \overline{B(x,r)}$ be a sequence with $\rho(x,a_n) \to \inf_{a' \in A} \rho(x,a')$ (such a sequence exists: see next paragraph). By taking a subsequence, we can assume $a_n \to a$ for some $a \in A$. It follows that $\rho(x,a) = \inf_{a' \in A} \rho(x,a')$ (triangle inequality).

Let $(a'_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset A$ have $\rho(x,a'_n) \to \inf_{a' \in A} \rho(x,a')$. Note that there is some $a \in B(x,r) \cap A$ by assumption, so $\inf_{a' \in A} \rho(x,a') < r$, and so we can find $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $\rho(x,a'_n) < r$.

Comment: "justify why this is possible"
Can you? It is very interesting for me. thank you!

Comment: @IlieWhite I have added clarification. Thank you for your comment, as it made me realize that I should have $B(x,r)$ be the *open* ball rather than the closed ball.

Comment: @eric-thoma So sorry, made mistake. Is it influences on ur solution?

Comment: @KEK_SAS My solution should be correct now.

Comment: Can I ask if the question was assuming that every closed ball is compact? I.e. this wasn't something that was proven right? (I think it is usually false in a general metric space because iirc it is equivalent to the Heine Borrell property) it was confusing from the way the question was worded.

Comment: @Countable Yes, this is assuming that every closed ball is compact. It is not always true if this is not the case.